# Rails Dreamhost Cron Job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cron, rake, dreamhost

I'm trying to get some cron jobs going through Dreamost using their panel. I'm also using rake to execute these jobs

My rake files are located in

app/lib/tasks/example.rake

But I don't know what code to give the panel to execute them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My recommendation would be to avoid trying to do that in the first place.

Editing cron jobs manually is a pain in the ass, and rails has some nice utilities to avoid it.

There's a railscast on using the wheneverize gem to prvent these problems.

http://asciicasts.com/episodes/164-cron-in-ruby

If you want these cron jobs to be automatically updated every time you deploy to dreamhost, just put it in as part of your Capistrano deploy.rb

If you're not using Capistrano, I strongly recommend you look into:

http://www.capify.org/index.php/Capistrano

**EDIT**

If you do want to take the DH cron route, the following should work

```
cd /full/path/to/your/project && rake example
```

Comment: You have some good suggestions, but the dreamhost panel is simple and that is the best way to add with dh because I heard that their bots kill long running processes

Comment: All the wheneverize gem does is simplify the creation of cron jobs. It literally modifies the crontab file. It's simply easier to maintain across multiple servers than having to manually edit cron files all over the place. 


Using wheneverize won't spawn a long running process

Comment: Yeah, your right. both process just edit the cron tab. I just setup wheneverize in literally 10 min and its great!

Answer (score -1):

if you're using rake, you could put

```
rake whatevertask
```

in the command field

Comment: my bad, i must've misunderstood where you said that the rake task executes the cron jobs, and the `rake whatever` is referring to what you would use in the control panel--nevermind